# How can I remap Unreal's Editor default movement (WASD) keys for a non-QWERTY keyboard

Tags: unreal-4, control

I am using a French (AZERTY) keyboard, and as such my "usual" game movment keys are ZQSD instead of WASD. I have been trying to change Unreal Editor's default keys to those I am accustomed to but I can't figure out how to do it.

Using UE 4.19.1

Here are the settings I've tried so far:

[image: Settings_1.png]
[image: Settings_2.png]
[image: Settings_3.png]

Answer (score 1):

Using the Top menu:

```
Edit --> Project Settings --> Engine / Input --> Bindings

e.g. Move Forward (W, S, Up, down)
```

This totally worked for me.  Obviously you will want to use the keyboard menu there.

ref: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/UI/ProjectSettings